# How to fix duplicate dependency in a gradle project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I found my web project always gives a error message.

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Invalid classpath publish/export dependency /Users/XXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.axis/axis-jaxrpc/1.4/b393f1f0c0d95b68c86d0b1ab2e687bb71f3c075/axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar. The project contains another dependency with the same archive name.    serverapi/api   Classpath Dependency Validator Message

And check the Gradle Dependecies, there are some duplicate jars.

```
axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar
axis-saaj-1.4.jar
```

So I create another simple project to verify this problem.
Here is the gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDir 'src'
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {  
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'axis:axis:1.4'
}
```

The gradle dependencies:

```
axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar
axis-saaj-1.4.jar
axis-wsdl4j1.5.1.jar
axis-1.4.jar
commons-discovery-2.0.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar
axis-saaj-1.4.jar
```

How to fix or report this problem?

Comment: These jars are not duplicated, the have different names and size.

Comment: No, I check they are directed to the same files in the gradle cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiDexEnabled in your gradle file like this.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `org.apache.axis:axis:1.4` instead of `axis:axis:1.4` might solve your problem.